# How can I check in a condition if an image field has value?

Tags: 7, rules

Is there any way to check if an image field has no value after saving the content? I tried with *Data Value is Empty*, but it doesn't work.

These are the exported rules I am using.

```json
{ "rules_autos_featured_listing_without_image" : {
    "LABEL" : "Autos: featured listing without image",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "autos" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--listing" : { "bundle" : "listing" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_listing_grouping" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_feature" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_images" } },
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "node:field-feature" ],
          "value" : { "value" : { "feature" : "feature" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "node:field-images" ] } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-listing-grouping" ], "value" : "1302" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the field you are trying to "test" (for its value), is available at the time [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) tries to do so.

That's why I always add a `entity_has_field` condition (and put it as the first condition) which looks something as in this example (part of a rules export of some rule):

```
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "account" ], "field" : "field_next_appointement" } }
],
```

In my sample here, it is related to entity `account`, and my field's machine name is `field_next_appointement`.

So retry your rule with the `Data Value is Empty` condition, but put such `entity_has_field` condition in front of it. So that in the end your rule has 2 conditions (no PHP coding at all involved), something like so:

- `entity has field` ...
- NOT `Data Value is Empty` ...

Below is a (simple) rule from my training class examples. It'll display a message like "*Watch, this is ONLY 100 EUR !!!!*" for a node which has a `field_article_price` field, whereas that price is exactly 100 EUR.

```
{ "rules_this_article_is_for_sale" : {
    "LABEL" : "This article is for sale",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_view" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_article_price" } },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:field-article-price" ], "value" : "100" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Watch, this is ONLY 100 EUR !!!!", "type" : "warning" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Looking at your (updated) question (now including your current rule), I think you should try to work step-by-step to investigate which part of your rule "doesn't" work. If I was in your shoes, I'd experiment with these variations (only for debugging):

1. Replace the ACTION with just a `drupal_message`:

   - if you get a message then, your problem is within ACTION. Todo: fix the Action.
   - if not your problem is in the EVENT of CONDITION(s). Todo: go to item 2.
2. Remove all CONDITION(s):

   - if you get a message then, your problem is within CONDITION(s). Todo: fix the CONDITION(s).
   - if not your problem is in the EVENT. Todo: go to item 3.
3. Review the EVENT: if the event you're trying to use to make the Rule work does not actually happen, or if you're "too late", then of course that needs to be fixed/reviewed. In my experience, there are quite a few Rules scenarios where you should use "When Drupal is initializing". My (personal favorite) sample of that is about "before content is going to be viewed" ...

I realize the above 3 steps do not actually "answer" your question, but they may help to debug what's actually the problem.

Comment: Thanks again Pierre for answering! so is this a custom PHP code condition? also I dont want to check if the entity has field, but if the field has value!

Comment: I updated my answer to try to reply to your comment above.

Comment: this is what I did the first place, unfortunately against all odds!! it doesn't work this way

Comment: actually it was a conflict on my side, it was okay at the first place, thanks!

Comment: actually now that I checked it more :D it doesnt really work for empty condition, I'll update the answer in a sec and thanks for being badass :D

Comment: also file fields such as image field, apparently doesn't work the same as other types of fileds in rules!