# How to get a conditional dependency to work?

Tags: 7, entities

I have 2 fields in my content type 'test':

1. 'Photos Gallery' -field type is image
2. 'Enable' checkbox to Enable gallery (field type boolean)

**Required output**: When 'Enable'-field is checked, the node should not allow us to save with empty photos in the 'Photos Gallery' field and we should be able to save if 'Enable' is unchecked.

I tried the **[Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module** and given condition like 'Gallery Photos is required when Enable is checked.', where 'Gallery photos' is dependent and 'Enable' is dependee field.

**Current output**: In the node edit page , when 'Enable' is checked, asterisk (*) can be seen near 'Gallery Photos' , but without adding photos if i save, it is allowing me to save, without any error.

What additional settings I need to do, apart from dependency settings?

**Note**: I'm also interested in possible alternative solutions to get this to work (instead of using [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)).

Comment: Are you interested in alternative solution (instead of conditional fields)?

Comment: sure..Is there any alternative solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative solution to using the conditional fields module (cfr your comment in your question), you can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. Here are some details (the pseudo code) about how to do so:

- **Rules Event**: Before saving content.
- **Rules Conditions**:

  1. Check for "entity has field" (for field = Enable)
  2. Check for "entity has field" (for field = Photos Gallery)
  3. Compare the value of the "*Enable*" field, for both the original value (before editing the field) and the (new) updated value, to verify if they enabled (checked) this field.
  4. Check if field "*Photos Gallery*" is empty.
- **Rules Action**: display an error message to explain that your validation failed. For an example of how to display an error message using rules, refer to my answer to "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326/how-to-make-the-permissions-of-a-module-more-granular)" (which actually includes 2 actions, you only want the `drupal_message` part of it (probably not the redirect to somewhere else).

To understand the need for those Rules Conditions "1." and "2.", have a look at my answer to "[How to check in a rules condition if an image field has value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171512/how-to-check-in-a-rules-condition-if-an-image-field-has-value)"

Should be straight forward to "develop" such rule, no (PHP) coding at all involved (only site building using admin UI).

## Video tutorials

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation,or else it was confusing.